# pandas append on columns with different names

Tags: python, pandas

How to append 2 different dataframes with different column names

```
a = pd.DataFrame({
    "id": [0,1,2,3],
    "countryid": [22,36,21,64],
    "famousfruit": ["banana", "apple", "mango", "orange"],
    "famousanimal": ["monkey", "elephant", "monkey", "horse"],
    "waterlvl": [23, 43, 41, 87]
}).set_index("id")

>> a
```

[image: a]

```
b = pd.DataFrame({
    "id": [0,1,2,3],
    "cid": [25,27,98,67],
    "FAM_FRUIT": ["grapes", "pineapple", "avacado", "orange"],
    "FAM_ANI": ["giraffe", "dog", "cat", "horse"],
}).set_index("id")

>>b
```

[image: b]

How to append the rows on **b** on the respective columns(whose names are different compared to **a**) and produce a result like below c

[image: c]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way I can think of to do this is to simply rename the columns in b to match those in a, then use the Pandas [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) function. Also best to [reset index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) if using this method

```
b.rename(columns={'FAM_FRUIT': 'famousfruit',
                 'FAM_ANI': 'famousanimal',
                 'cid': 'countryid'}, inplace=True)
a = pd.concat([a, b])
a.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

Outer join via [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) is one way. Since this an outer join, `on` parameter need not be specified as `pandas` will use common columns.

```
b = b.rename(columns={'FAM_FRUIT': 'famousfruit',
                      'FAM_ANI': 'famousanimal',
                      'cid': 'countryid'})

a.merge(b, how='outer')

#    countryid famousanimal famousfruit  waterlvl
# 0         22       monkey      banana      23.0
# 1         36     elephant       apple      43.0
# 2         21       monkey       mango      41.0
# 3         64        horse      orange      87.0
# 4         25      giraffe      grapes       NaN
# 5         27          dog   pineapple       NaN
# 6         98          cat     avacado       NaN
# 7         67        horse      orange       NaN
```

Comment: Don't need the `on` kwarg.