# Stack/Join/Merge two different DataFrame of different numbers of rows & columns

Tags: python, pandas

**Input**
Df1:

```
    A    B    C
a   2    4    4
b   1    6    3
c   4    2    8
```

Df2:

```
P    Q    R    S    T
5    3    8    3    0
4    8    6    8    3
```

**Desired Output**

```
    A    B    C
a   2    4    4
b   1    6    3
c   4    2    8
P    Q    R    S    T
5    3    8    3    0
4    8    6    8    3
```

I want to connect `Df1` and `Df2` one below each other as shown above.
How can I do that?

Comment: would the [P    Q    R    S    T] be a row in the final dataframe?

Comment: Off topic : What is the use case for this? Just curious why do you want this. Are you sure this isn't a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: When concatenating/appending two dataframes they need to have similar column names. So you would have rename Df2 columns then concat them. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48792037/pandas-append-on-columns-with-different-names

Comment: @DavidGibson No I cant not give extra columns name to any of the DataFrame.

Comment: @anky I am saving these two DataFrame in .csv format on the same sheet and same manner

Comment: @Mit In actual These two dataframes are very big. Df1 (9 * 3) & Df2 ( 8760 * 7)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you need it, but the code below will make the trick:

```
import pandas as pd

# initialize dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[2, 4, 4], [1, 6, 3], [4, 2, 8]],
                   columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], index=['a', 'b', 'c'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[3, 8, 3, 0], [8, 6, 8, 3]],
                   columns=['Q', 'R', 'S', 'T'], index=[5, 4])
df2.index.name = 'P'

# prepare for concat
df2.loc[df2.index.name] = df2.columns
df2.index = df2.index.astype(str)
df2 = df2.sort_index(ascending=False)
df2.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', '']
df2.index.name = ''

df1[''] = ['','','']


# concat
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

Output:

```
In [2]: df1
Out[2]: 
   A  B  C  
a  2  4  4  
b  1  6  3  
c  4  2  8  

In [3]: df2
Out[3]: 
   A  B  C   
             
P  Q  R  S  T
5  3  8  3  0
4  8  6  8  3

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
   A  B  C   
a  2  4  4   
b  1  6  3   
c  4  2  8   
P  Q  R  S  T
5  3  8  3  0
4  8  6  8  3
```

Comment: My DataFrame shapes are Df1 (9 * 3) & Df2 ( 8760 * 7). I have tried but not working

Comment: I would like to help, however the code in the answer does exactly what you asked in the question. Could you maybe be more precise and explain what you actually need?